# ISP SIP account on own Asterisk machine

Tags: asterisk, sip

I'm new to VoIP and SIP, have experience in Linux and servers in general just not SIP servers and such.

I was curious about experimenting a little with SIP and VoIP. So I ordered a SIP account from my ISP. Obviously they provide the number and their own SIP server. Basically all I have to do is hook up a SIP-box with the correct information and I can start receiving calls. I believe they use Asterisk.

But I was wondering if I could take this SIP account and set up my own Asterisk and sort of have my own exchange? Is this what SIP trunking is?

Basically what I would like to do is somehow set up my own Asterisk (or similar) on one of my own servers and be able to see incoming and outgoing calls and redirect from my own server, so basically I would only use my ISP server for "connecting" the call itself.

Is this possible? I'd appreciate any information on the topic and any helpful links would be great.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Try googling for asterisk information, there's a ton out there.  You might want to read the O'Reilly book if searching the web isn't your style.

Comment: But what is it called? What should I look for? Is this essentially what SIP trunking is?